# How to Query database to grab product orders to user profile

Tags: php, laravel

Just started learning laravel/PHP and i am having a bit of trouble querying the user order on the user profile page. So after the user purchases the product i would like the order to displayed on the user personal page. What the correct way of going about that. So how do i query the database correctly so that on the user profile page it show the product name, qty and the total for the item that was just purchased.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Order;

class UserProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function index(User $user)
    {
      $orders=Order::where('user_id',$user->id)->latest()->get();
      return view('profile.index', compact('user','orders'));
    }

}
```

Not sure if this correct

---

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
  <h2> {{$user->name}}</h2>

  @forelse($orders as $order)
    <h4>{{$order->total}}</h4>


    @empty

    <h5>No items</h5>


    @endforelse
  </div>



</div>




@endsection
```

[image]

Comment: You already inserting user_id in orders table so you can easily get all orders of particular use in user profile as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your user Model :

```
public function orders(){
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class)->latest();
}
```

in your Order Model

```
//For the listing of product in an order
public function products(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

In your controller

```
public function index(User $user)
    {
      $user->load('orders.products');
      return view('profile.index', compact('user'));
    }
```

In your view

```
@forelse($user->orders as $order)

    <h4>{{$order->total}}</h4>
          @forelse($order->products as $product)
              {{ $product->name }}
          @empty
              no product
          @endforelse


    @empty

    <h5>No items</h5>


@endforelse
```

Comment: thanks so what if i want to grab the product name how would i do that i got the total now ? @matheuFerre

Comment: I have edited my answer with the order -> products relation

Comment: thank you so much really helped me alot i got it! @mathieuFerre

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks wrong. You are using latest() to return the most recent order in the table, but then using a get. If you want just the last order I would use first()

```
 $orders=Order::where('user_id',$user->id)->latest()->first();
```

I guess though you don't want a single row, but all rows, in which case remove latest()

```
$orders=Order::where('user_id',$user->id)->get();
```

And then probably use orderBy('created_at') or similar to get the most recent first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$data = ['user' => $user, 'orders' => $orders];
return view('profile.index', $data);
```